# How do I launch Windows Calendar to show a specific day?

Tags: windows, delphi, calendar, windows-vista

I want to launch Windows Calendar viewing a certain day. Is there any way to do this?

[I already did the same thing with Calendar on Window Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911847.aspx), but the same way doesn't work on Windows Vista.

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: My version of Windows doesn't come with a calendar. And Andreas is right, this looks like off topic for SO.

Comment: @David: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Calendar. In Windows 7, there is only the Windows Live Mail (optional).

Comment: @Andreas The Vista calendar was rather good. You could sync it nicely with a Blackberry and indeed other devices. But it was canned from Win 7. So, Google Calendar now wins!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Yes, I made a program that needs to launch Windows Calendar in a certain day to show him appointments made by the program.

Comment: @David Heffernan Read above comment.

Comment: And you only care about Windows Vista? That's the only OS you want to support?

Comment: Evidently yes, @David, since that's the only OS where the program in question exists.

Comment: The Vista Windows Calendar had an API for programatically interacting with it (probably through COM Automation). I'm not familiar with it at all, but found a link to a [CodePlex article](http://c4fdevkit.codeplex.com) with information and both VB.NET and C# code examples. They were written for Visual Studio 2008 Express, so they're not too terribly old either.